# Is it possible to extract a table create DDL statement from bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl

I don't see any way of doing that in the Web UI nor bq (although I can't say that I've exhaustively studied the entire corpus of bq options).

Edit:

Several people marked this question as a duplicating a question that has already been answered.

But the answer to that question, while giving useful, related information, for which I am appreciative, did not answer the above question, which I will try to rephrase in a more precise manner:  "Is it possible to extract a table create DDL statement for a specific table that currently exists in bigquery?  And if so, how?"

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 1) given a particular table 2) generate a `CREATE TABLE` statement that would produce a table with the same schema. There isn't a nice way to do this currently--you'd need to get the table schema through the API and generate the statement programmatically--but consider "starring" the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063) for updates.

Comment: @scott-wood - unfortunately this happens when you have few-in-one type of question. I would recommend you to update title of referenced question to reflect 'how one might create a nullable repeated column' part of it. so then we can try to re-open this current question (or you can just simply ask it again) so it will be answered without risk of being marked as a duplicate based on just question's title

Comment: @scott-wood - meantime, another option (in addition to provided by Elliott) would be to use [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) to try to find statement that created that query (assuming that a) you have audit enabled and b) that table was created  using DDL)